# MySQL cluster NDB "table is full" when create table

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

For testing purpose, I setup a MySQL cluster with 3 Amazon EC2 Medium (1 core, 2 ecu, 3.7GB ram, ubuntu 12.04 lts): 1 machine for mgm + sql, another 2 machines for the data nodes. Here the config.ini which is generated by the auto installer (for a template for me in future):

```
[NDB_MGMD DEFAULT]
Portnumber=1186

[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=49
HostName=10.0.0.10
DataDir=/usr/local/mysql/data/49/
Portnumber=1186

[TCP DEFAULT]
SendBufferMemory=4M
ReceiveBufferMemory=4M

[NDBD DEFAULT]
BackupMaxWriteSize=1M
BackupDataBufferSize=16M
BackupLogBufferSize=4M
BackupMemory=20M
BackupReportFrequency=10
MemReportFrequency=30
LogLevelStartup=15
LogLevelShutdown=15
LogLevelCheckpoint=8
LogLevelNodeRestart=15
DataMemory=650M
IndexMemory=120M
MaxNoOfTables=4096
MaxNoOfTriggers=3500
NoOfReplicas=2
StringMemory=25
DiskPageBufferMemory=64M
SharedGlobalMemory=20M
LongMessageBuffer=32M
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=16384
BatchSizePerLocalScan=512
FragmentLogFileSize=256M
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=3
RedoBuffer=32M
MaxNoOfExecutionThreads=2
StopOnError=false
LockPagesInMainMemory=1
TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=32000
TimeBetweenWatchdogCheckInitial=60000
TransactionInactiveTimeout=60000
HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=15000
HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=15000

[NDBD]
NodeId=1
HostName=10.0.0.21
DataDir=/usr/local/mysql/data/1/

[NDBD]
NodeId=2
HostName=10.0.0.22
DataDir=/usr/local/mysql/data/2/

[MYSQLD DEFAULT]

[MYSQLD]
NodeId=53
HostName=10.0.0.10
```

The cluster started well. Then I tried to import a sample Joomla db which I've changed a bit: InnoDB to NDB and some large VARCHAR fields to TEXT fields. But after some tables was imported successfully, I got errors on next tables: `Error Code: 1114. The table 'xxx' is full`. The next table is very very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `joomla_finder_links_terms3` (
  `link_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `term_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `weight` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`,`term_id`),
  KEY `idx_term_weight` (`term_id`,`weight`),
  KEY `idx_link_term_weight` (`link_id`,`term_id`,`weight`)
) ENGINE=NDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I checked MemoryUsage and it's just 1%:

```
ndb_mgm -e 'all report MemoryUsage'
Connected to Management Server at: 10.0.0.10:1186
Node 1: Data usage is 1%(286 32K pages of total 20640)
Node 1: Index usage is 1%(259 8K pages of total 14752)
Node 2: Data usage is 1%(286 32K pages of total 20640)
Node 2: Index usage is 1%(259 8K pages of total 14752)
```

Could anyone tell me I've done wrong? Thank in adv.

[EDIT 1]

Note: the sample db is just structure, no data, no row.

Comment: Ok solved it. I can't answer my own question so I put it to here.

In case of a `"table is full"` error, we should run `SHOW WARNINGS;` (right after the query which causes error) to see what exactly causes this error and fix it. In my case, it's because of `MaxNoOfAttributes` and `MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes`. I needed to increase them.